# Less css with optional parameters

Tags: less, default-value, optional-parameters

This might be a quick and easy question, but I was still unable to find the answer.

In less, is there any way of using a mixin (say `.mixin(@a: 2, @b: 3) { /* css here */ }`) and only supplying values for given parameters? I know I can use this as `.mixin(5)` which would be the same as `.mixin(5, 3)`, but can I do something like `.mixin(@b: 5)`? Meaning the same as `.mixin(2, 5)` (however I wouldn't have to know the value of a to use the default).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In less using the dotless compiler you can do

.mixin(@b:3);

This will be in the original less.js in 1.3.1 (the next release)- see https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/268

Comment: in where? if its in less.js, then 1.3.1 hasn't yet been released - are you using the latest from the repository?

Comment: Ah, I miss read that part about it not being released yet. I'm using the LESS.app to compile. Looking at the Version History it's not been updated yet. http://incident57.com/less/versionHistory.html Digging around the app now to try and update it myself.